# Rotate monitor 2° counterclockwise?

Tags: software-recommendation, display, monitor

Ubuntu's Monitor Preferences tool (listed as Monitors in the Dash) is able to orient the screen Left, Right, Normal or Upside Down, but is there a tool that can rotate the screen *just a little*? My CRT's screen is rotated perhaps 2° counterclockwise and I was wondering if this is something I can fix with software. This monitor (a GVC MPR II) doesn't appear to have user serviceable settings to fix the problem.

I'm using an ATI Radeon graphics card and the proprietary drivers, if that matters. I looked for a setting to adjust in ATI Catalyst Control, without success.

**Edit:** I found a tiny adjustment knob on the bottom of the back of the monitor and was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can fix this problem via some software setting - for one thing, rotating the screen "just a little" would require quite a bit of processing power - and it still would be a picture rotated *inside* the skewed rectangle your monitor displays - hope you see what I'm trying to say.

In other words, it's most likely an electrical problem which can only be fixed by adjusting some pots inside the monitor, not via software.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean about rotating the screen inside the skewed rectangle. That's what I was afraid of...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the proprietary ATI drivers, but the RandR protocol does support setting a 3x3 transformation matrix.

This can be configured using the `--transform` option to the `xrandr` tool.  The man page gives a good description of how to structure the parameters, including how to create a rotation matrix.

If that doesn't help, you could always try a low tech solution like propping up one edge of the monitor stand ...

Comment: If I understand right, the transformation will be applied to an already finished pixmap of the screen, which I suspect will degrade the quality considerably (sub-pixel font rendering, for instance). NIce to know that there is `--transform`, though, never spotted it before.

Comment: That is true.  I believe one of the initial reasons for the feature was to allow software correction of the perspective of image from a data projector that can't perform the correction optically.  It is for cases where overall shape is more important than fine detail.